# Knockout Javascript any strategies for making a foreach checkbox section with a bound observable array

Tags: foreach, knockout.js, checked, ko.observablearray

Basically I'm making a repeatable section and I want to have the checked state of all checkboxes pre-supplied by an array.

```
            <div style="height: 100%; border: 1px solid grey; overflow-y: scroll;" id="AssociatedUsers" data-bind="foreach: AllUserList">
                <input type='checkbox' class='cSupUser' style="width:20px;margin:2px" value="$data" data-bind='checked: supplierUsers' /><span data-bind='text: $data.Text'></span><br />
            </div>
```

But obviously value="$data" is just returning the string "$data". I've decided to start working on a solution where I just map the array with json strings when I save and load the related data, but this adds complication and feels like a hack, so I was wondering if there is a better way to handle this situation. I would also prefer supplierUsers could just be mapped directly to the viewModel, because I'm going to be generating the response to the server from the viewModel, but it seems like observableArrays don't work for that parameter.

I'm only 3 days into using knockout framework, any help/suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: This has been answered before - I actually just researched this same problem. Here are links to the questions and the fiddles with their answers that I found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736136/working-with-checkboxes-in-knockoutjs http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/vgBUf/ also: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/knockoutjs/FQgAXguUFtY http://jsfiddle.net/AvFRK/

Answer (score 1):

The way i've dealt with this is to use the `attr` binding for each checkbox. E.G.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked : supplierUsers, attr : { value : $data}" />
```