# Item selection MVC view with KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am trying to implement a generic ASP.net MVC view. The UI should display a list of available and selected items loading data (basically list of string) from server. User can make changes into the list i.e. can select new items from available item list and also can remove items from selected list.

I wanted to do it using KnockoutJS as to take advantage of binding.

I manage to complete it upto the point everything is working except showing selected item as checked when the view is initialized in available list. E.g. [As Shown Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/GErdL/)

I tried various options ([using template (closest to what I want to achieve)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736136/working-with-a-list-of-checkboxes-in-knockoutjs), [Checked attr](http://geekswithblogs.net/codesailor/archive/2013/08/08/153656.aspx), [possible options](http://ryanrahlf.com/building-select-lists-with-knockout-js-part-1/)), the issue is if I manage to display item checked some other functionality breaks. Tried defining a template but could not get it to work in my case.

HTML:

```
<div class='moverBoxOuter'>
<div id='contactsList'>
    <span data-bind="visible: availableItems().length > 0">Available countries: </span>
    <ul data-bind="foreach: availableItems, visible: availableItems().length > 0">
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: $root.selectedItems" />
            <span data-bind="text: title"></span>
        </li> 
    </ul>

    <span data-bind="visible: selectedItems().length > 0">Selected countries: </span>

    <ul data-bind="foreach: selectedItems, visible: selectedItems().length > 0">
        <li>
            <span data-bind="text: title"></span>
            <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeItem">Delete</a>
        </li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
    var initialData = [
    {
        availableItems: [
          { title: "US", isSelected: true },
          { title: "Canada", isSelected: false },
          { title: "India", isSelected: false }]
    },
    {
        selectedItems: [
          { "title": "US" },
          { "title": "Canada" }
        ]
    }
];

function Item(titleText, isSelected) {
    this.title = ko.observable(titleText);
    this.isSelected = ko.observable(isSelected);
}

var SelectableItemViewModel = function (items) {
    // Data
    var self = this;

    self.availableItems = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(items[0].availableItems, function (item) {
        return new Item(item.title, item.isSelected);
    }));

    self.selectedItems = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(items[1].selectedItems, function (item) {
        return new Item(item.title, item.isSelected);
    }));

    // Operations
    self.selectItem = function (item) {
        self.selectedItems.push(item);
        item.isSelected(!item.isSelected());
    };

    self.removeItem = function (removedItem) {
        self.selectedItems.remove(removedItem);
        $.each(self.availableItems, function (item) {
            if (item.title === removedItem.title) {
                item.isSelected = false;
            }
        });
    };
}

var vm = new SelectableItemViewModel(initialData);

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

Could you please help, see jsfiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/sbirthare/KR4a6/6/

**Update: Follow up question below **

Its followup question:

I need to add a combobox on same UI e.g. for US state. The available items are counties, based on user selection in state combo I need to filter out counties. I am getting data from server using AJAX and its all successful BUT the displayed list is not refreshing. I was expecting having binding setup correctly, if we change the observable array in viewmodel, the UI should change. I tried forcing change to availableItems but it just display all items. Please see if you can spot the problem in below code where I am updating ViewModel observable array.

```
function multiselect_change() {

            console.log("event: openmultiselect_change");

            var selectedState = $("#stateDropdownSelect").val();

            var propertyName = $("#PropertyName").val();
            var searchId = @Model.SearchId;
            var items;

            var model = { propertyName: propertyName, searchId: searchId, stateName: selectedState };
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("GetFilterValues", "Search")',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: JSON.stringify(model)
            })
                .success(function(result) {
                    debugger;

                    items = JSON.parse(result);

                    vm.availableItems(items.AvailableItems);

                    //vm.availableItems.valueHasMutated();

                    //var item = document.getElementById('availableItemId');
                    //ko.cleanNode(item);
                    //ko.applyBindings(vm, item);

                    vm.filter(selectedState);
                })
                .error(function(xhr, status) {
                    alert(status);
                });        
    }
```

Comment: what's the issue? I see everything is working fine in given fiddle.

Comment: In current fiddle when u run, US and Canada should be checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user3426870 mentioned, you need to change the value you passed to the checked binding to boolean.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: isSelected" />
```

Also, I don't think you need to have selectedItems in the initial data.

Instead in the viewModel, you can do something like:

```
self.selectedItems = ko.computed(function() {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.availableItems(), function (item) {
                return item.isSelected();
            });
        });
```

Comment: Thanks Jerry, I tried that. "fiddle.jshell.net/sbirthare/KR4a6/10/" Still not able to crack it.

Comment: Thank you so much Jerry, it works, great! You have achieved this using single collection, any idea what was the problem with my code (two collection). Wondering can it not be achieved keeping two collection (as in my current code). I am asking as I am going to add more logic in future for which I will need to keep two separate collection.

Comment: It was to do with the way how you initialised selectedItems in the viewModel. Both collections need to contain the same objects; not different objects with the same data.

I have updated the fiddle with how selected items should be initialised:

http://jsfiddle.net/KR4a6/13

Comment: Hi Jerry, I added a follow up question. I spent a lot of time to crack it but could not. Please see if u can help. Thanks.

Comment: Had a quick look and am not sure if I fully understand. Would it be possible to provide a fiddle with the updated code? I will be unavailable for another few days though... so you might consider asking a new question in order for other people to see it.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. Sorry I am unable to provide the jsfiddle at the moment but its exactly what you provided to me. All i am trying is, update/filter availableItems based on user selection after viewmodel is initialized. Initializing availableItems should refresh the UI, isnt it?  I will raise a new question tomorrow :)

Comment: I got the answer, it was due to minified versoin of knochoutjs causing problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you give an array to the binding `checked` while it's supposed to be a value comparable to `true` or `false` (like `undefind` or an empty string). 
I would use a function checking if the `$data` is in your array and returning a boolean to your binding.

Something like that!

Comment: Do you mean something like this "http://fiddle.jshell.net/sbirthare/KR4a6/10/" Thanks but still not able to crack it. By any chance u can work on fiddle please.

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/KR4a6/11/ (I did not remove the "useless" content, just add mine).
I used the computed function of Jerry, it's a better way to take advantage of the Knockout binding mechanism.

Comment: I checked you changes, initial load works fine however delete does not. Anyways thank for suggestion and your time. Appreciated. Jerry solution works....