# Filtering bounded item using knockoutjs

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

Following the help provided to my previous question [Item selection MVC view with KnockoutJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23285882/item-selection-mvc-view-with-knockoutjs), i was able to achieve what i was after at that point of time. It was known that a new requirement will come sooner and here it is. I need to display a combobox that should filter (change) the list of total available items. There are many examples out there that I referred and tried in my example [Selection List](http://jsfiddle.net/sbirthare/KR4a6/16/).

My simplistic view:

```
<h3>Filter Available Items By Name: </h3>
<p>Type letters: <input data-bind="value: filter, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" /></p>

    <div id='contactsList'>
        <span data-bind="visible: availableItems().length > 0">Available countries: </span>
        <ul data-bind="foreach: filteredItems, visible: availableItems().length > 0">
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: $root.selectedItems" />
                <span data-bind="text: title"></span>
            </li> 
        </ul>

        <span data-bind="visible: selectedItems().length > 0">Selected countries: </span>

        <ul data-bind="foreach: selectedItems, visible: selectedItems().length > 0">
            <li>
                <span data-bind="text: title"></span>
                <a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeItem">Delete</a>
            </li> 
        </ul>
    </div>
```

ViewModel:

```
var initialData = [
    {
        availableItems: [
          { title: "US", isSelected: true },
          { title: "Canada", isSelected: false },
          { title: "India", isSelected: false }]
    },
    {
        selectedItems: [
          { "title": "US" },
          { "title": "Canada" }
        ]
    }
];

function Item(titleText, isSelected) {
    this.title = ko.observable(titleText);
    this.isSelected = ko.observable(isSelected);
}

var SelectableItemViewModel = function (items) {
    // Data
    var self = this;
    self.filter = ko.observable("");
    self.availableItems = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(items[0].availableItems, function (item) {
        return new Item(item.title, item.isSelected);
    }));

    self.selectedItems = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(items[1].selectedItems, function (item) {
        return ko.utils.arrayFirst(self.availableItems(), function (itm){
            return item.title == itm.title();
        });

    }));

        //filter the items using the filter text
    self.filteredItems = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        debugger;
        var filter = this.filter().toLowerCase();
        if (!filter) {
            return this.availableItems();
        } else {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.availableItems(), function (item) {
                return ko.utils.stringStartsWith(item.title().toLowerCase(), filter);
            });
        }
    }, self);

    // Operations

    self.removeItem = function (removedItem) {
        self.selectedItems.remove(removedItem);
    };
}

var vm = new SelectableItemViewModel(initialData);

$(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});
```

For simplicity I am just trying to achieve it on a keystroke in a text box (i am hoping once I achieve that the combobox item selection change will work smoothly).

The problem is, no matter what, the list displayed using filteredItems does not get refreshed. I even tried to other ways shown in previous question [Item selection MVC view with KnockoutJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23285882/item-selection-mvc-view-with-knockoutjs), in update section.

I suspect it is due to the way availableItems and selectedItems are connected together but I am not sure what's wrong.

I see on text box keystroke, viewmodel filteredItems is getting called (noticed an error in chrome in my jsfiddle though, could that be the issue, same function works in others jsfiddle). I did matched the libraries exactly with no help to avoid those errors.

Please help me to fix this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your JsFiddle, the problem is that `ko.utils.stringStartsWith` is not available. This is an internal function to knockout that gets removed when you are using the minified version.

The best solution is to write your own `startsWith` function, or find one using google, or get one from another library if you are using one.

Comment: Sport on!!! I changed the external resources to debug version and it all worked as I expected. Thank you so much.