# How do I select an invisible checkbox using Knockout JS?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I want to select a (invisible) checkbox by clicking the `div`:

```
<div class="my-button" data-bind="click: selected">
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selected" /> A
</div>

<div class="my-button" data-bind="click: selected">
    <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" data-bind="checked: selected" /> B
</div>

<div class="my-button" data-bind="click: selected">
    <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" data-bind="checked: selected" /> C
</div>

// JS code
var selectedlModel = function() {        
    var self = this;
    self.selected = ko.observable(false);        
}

ko.applyBindings(selectedlModel());
```

The above code is not working. [See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spstieng/VUk6J/).

I'm also wondering - in Angular one can do something like this:

```
data-bind="checked: clicked ? true : false"
```

and I don't have to write any code in my JS file. Is this possible in Knockout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need a separate observable for each (hidden) checkbox, and like Polly Shaw says, the [`click:`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html) binding expects a function while [`checked:`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/checked-binding.html) expects a boolean.

Personally i use this sort of thing quite often so I made a small helper function to create toggleable items for me. Here is an example:

#### viewmodel

```js
function toggleable(name) {
    var self = {};
    self.name = name;
    self.checked = ko.observable(false);
    self.toggle = function () {
        self.checked(!self.checked());
    };
    return self;
}

function ViewModel() {        
    var self = this;
    // array of checkboxes
    self.checkboxes = ["A", "B", "C"].map(toggleable); // make each a toggleable object
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

#### template

```html
<div data-bind="foreach: checkboxes">
    <div class="my-button" data-bind="click: toggle">
        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: checked" hidden /> <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VUk6J/5/

Note: it does not matter if the checkboxes are hidden or not, but if they are, consider styling them differently ;)

http://jsfiddle.net/VUk6J/6/ (Same JS, added a `css:` binding and a class in the css)

Comment: Thanks @xec, nice and clean solution. I just have one problem. The checkboxes are retrieved from the database, so creating the array in JS is not possible. How would you go about mapping the "static" checkboxes?

Comment: @Steven The clean way would be to pass the data (JSON is nice for this) to your script instead of generating the html server-side. How precisely you would do this depends on your server side tech of choice.

Comment: That's what I though. Though its easier / simpler to get data from server side (PHP), it seems Knockout is based on retrieving data through Ajax. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be because your click is bound to a property rather than an event. Perhaps you need to add a behaviour? See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VUk6J/3/

```
var selectedlModel = function() {        
    var self = this;
    self.selected = ko.observable(false);
    self.clickSelected = function() { self.selected(!self.selected());};
}

ko.applyBindings(selectedlModel());


<div class="my-button" data-bind="click: clickSelected">
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: selected" /> A
</div>

<div class="my-button" data-bind="click: clickSelected">
    <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" data-bind="checked: selected" /> B
</div>

<div class="my-button" data-bind="click: clickSelected">
    <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" data-bind="checked: selected" /> C
</div>
```

Comment: Um... closer. But clicking A will also select B and C. I just want to select the item I click.

Comment: OK I've edited it so that it toggles the check. Clicking A also selects B and C because they're all bound to the same 'selected' property - I think you need an observable array. I have to go home now but I can show you later tonight if nobody else has answered it.

Comment: Hmm.. do I really have to do something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736136/working-with-a-list-of-checkboxes-in-knockoutjs If yes, then using normal jQuery is a lot easier (and less code)